# Java SecretWord Code

Tags: java

I am making basic java program to hold a secret word (mouse) and allow a user to guess letters. The program will end either when the user guesses all the letters in the word, or when they guess 7 wrong letters. Whenever I type any letter into the program, it will run through it without giving the user an option to enter another letter. What should I add so that it will only run the program once per letter entered? Also if it wasnt quite obvious I am new to coding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessWord
{
    String Secretword="mouse";
    String letter;
    int index;
    private int number;
    private int counter;
    private String guesses;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public GuessWord()
    {
        String Secretword="";
        String letter = "";
        String guesses = "";
        int number = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int index = 0;
    }

    public String getLetter(){
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter");
    letter = scan.next();
    return letter;
    }

    public void calc(){ 
        guesses=letter;
        while(number <= 7 && counter<5)
        {
            if(Secretword.indexOf(letter) != -1)
            {
                index = Secretword.indexOf(letter);
                System.out.println("You entered a letter in the word");
                counter++;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("You entered an incorrect letter");
                number++;
            }
            guesses=guesses+" " +letter;
            System.out.println("The letters you have guessed are:" + guesses);
            }

            String str;
        if(number == 7){
            System.out.println("You lose");
        }else 
        {
            System.out.println("You win");
        }
        }

}//class




public class GuessWordR
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    GuessWord g1 = new GuessWord();
    g1.getLetter();
    g1.calc();
    }//class    
}//main
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that you're declaring new variables in your constructor instead of setting the default values for the instance variables. `Whenever I type any letter into the program, it will run through it without giving the user an option to enter another letter.` maybe it is because you're never asking for more letters. Your loop will always "evaluate" the one and only letter the user had entered in the `main` method.

Comment: @Tom Oh thats obvious. Thanks. Ill just move the question into the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean flag and run it in a loop. but for that you need to restructure your code as well. First fix the calc() method

```
public boolean calc() {
    guesses = letter;
    if (number <= 7 && counter < 5) {
        if (Secretword.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
            index = Secretword.indexOf(letter);
            System.out.println("You entered a letter in the word");
            counter++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered an incorrect letter");
            number++;
        }
        guesses = guesses + " " + letter;
        System.out.println("The letters you have guessed are:" + guesses);
    }

    String str;
    if (number == 7) {
        System.out.println("You lose");
        return true;
    } else if (counter == 5) {
        System.out.println("You win");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your main method should be update like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuessWord g1 = new GuessWord();
    boolean completed = false;
    while (!completed) {
        g1.letter = g1.getLetter();
        completed = g1.calc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a while loop.

So while some condition is not met keep asking the user to enter a new key.

Perhaps add a new method to the GuessWord Class

```
public void startGuessing() {
   while(hasGuesses /* some boolean flag */) {
         getLetter()
         getCalc()
   }
}
```

And then call that method in your main method instead of `getLetter()` and `getCalc()`.

You will need to add a `boolean` variable to your class to indicate when to exit this while loop and the logic to keep count of the number of failed guesses etc.

Answer (score 0):

you ask user for input unless condition get satisfied instead of asking and calculating once. And read char by char input instead of reading whole string.
something like:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
      GuessWord g1 = new GuessWord();

      while(number <= 7 && counter<5){
            g1.getLetter();
            g1.calc();
      }
}//class
```

Comment: `number` and `counter` are not static. And they shouldn't be changed to `static`.